# Token 'currentTab' is at column {2} of the expression [{3}] starting at [{4}]

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I got an error of Token 'currentTab' is at column {2} of the expression [{3}] starting at [{4}].

here is what I want to do:

```
<a href="javascript:;" data-toggle="tab" ng-click="currentTab=4">
```

set my tab to set currentTab to a value

> ```
> <div class="active" id="note-tab" ng-show="currentTab==1">
> ```

use ng-show to make active tab visible

> ```
> <button class="post-btn" ng-click="postStatus({{currentTab}})">Post</button>
> ```

in the same time, set currentTab as parameter for the postStatus function on a button

what's wrong with my procedure?

Comment: `postStatus({{currentTab}})` should be `postStatus(currentTab)`